# Moshi equivalent of Gson's "serializeNulls"

Tags: json, gson, moshi

I recently replaced Moshi for Gson in a backend that's expected to serialize responses with nullable values as `{ "value": null }`, instead of `{}`.

Neither Moshi nor Gson do this by default, but Gson has an option to do it directly in the builder:

`Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create()`.

Does Moshi have support for something similar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can call serializeNulls() on any JsonAdapter to get a JsonAdapter that'll serialize nulls.